UNITY In scroll view rect , how do I drag when I click on the childs?
Consider the following set up, I have a 2D like array using scrollviewrect vertical and vertial layout group. And then in side with child of horizontal layout group.
EDIT: It happens when I run the game, not in the editor.
EDIT2: The map icons are Buttons, I have tried removing the Button script but it is still the same

My issue is I can drag it up and down only if I click between the icons, but when I click on the icons it wont drag.
Is it because my icon have click event implemented that blocks the drag event? How do I fix it?


The solution is close to what TheQuaX has, but I find a better way which is to pass the event to the scroll.
Here is the code I found on unity forum.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/child-objects-blocking-scrollrect-from-scrolling.311555/
public class FixScrollRect: MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler,  IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IScrollHandler
{
    public ScrollRect MainScroll;
 
 
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        MainScroll.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
    }
 
 
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        MainScroll.OnDrag(eventData);
    }
 
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        MainScroll.OnEndDrag(eventData);
    }
 
 
    public void OnScroll(PointerEventData data)
    {
        MainScroll.OnScroll(data);
    }
 
 
}


You can't drag them because they are being affected by the layout group, that's like... what it's made for. To change the locations of "map icons", you can only resize the "Content" object or change the values in the vertical layout group.


Looks like my question is confusing, I will add some clarification.
What I meant was, when I run the game I can drag the scroll view, but  if I rag on the "map icons" it wont move, I have to click between the icons in order to drag the scroll

May I ask which unity version you are using? I had this incident in older versions, but that was a long time ago.

2022.3.4f1, may be it was because the icon's event block the scroll event, i will try it tonight

As you mentioned, the click event on your MapIcon can be blocking the scroll event. To fix this, you can could use Unity's EventTrigger to check between click and drag events. Start a timer at PointerDown and then check at PointerUp if the elapsed time is less than a threshold. If it's smaller, it's a click event else, it's a drag event.
Something like:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MapIconClickHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    private bool isDragging;
    private float timePointerDown;
    public float clickTime = 0.2f; // Maximum time until a pointerdown/up is considered a click

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        timePointerDown = Time.time;
        isDragging = false;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (Time.time - timePointerDown > clickTime)
            isDragging = true;

        if (!isDragging)
        {
            // Handle Click event
            Debug.Log("ClickEvent");
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle Drag event
            Debug.Log("DragEvent");
        }
    }
}

Edit:
When need the buttons, then leave your button scrip and simply add following to your MapIconButton:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public ScrollRect scrollRect;

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // calculate mouse y position delta 
        float delta = eventData.delta.y;

        // update vertikaleNormalizedPosition based on mouse movement
        scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition += delta * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

You can play with normalizing the mouse input, but for the sake of simplicity, this template should be enough.

What if the map icons are Buttons? I have tried removing the Button script from the icons and they still cant be dragged.
Should I try passing the event to the lower layer? Not sure how to do that...

Same issue. Try removing the collider as well from the icon and you should be able to drag-scroll. When you want them to be clickable leave the collider attached and implement something like in my answer and attach the script to your icon. The collider with raycast will block your scrolling, but inside the drag event you can scroll via script. I will update my answer.
